# How to install omake utility in Windows

Tags: ocaml, omake

I want to install the omake utility in Windows , I am referring to this utility.

Github link : https://github.com/ocaml-omake/omake

In the INSTALL file it is saying ocaml installs the omake utility , but when I do 
ocaml build.ml -install
I get following error : 
**** Fatal error: Cannot find file "libws2_32"**